# Remove add_menu()'s second argument from it's submenus list

Tags: dashboard

I use [`add_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/), then I add number of [`add_submenu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/).

**CODE**

```
    add_menu_page( 'Config', 'MDW Config', 'manage_options', 'mdw-config', 'config_general_info', '', 45);
    add_submenu_page( 'mdw-config', 'General info', 'Info', 'manage_options', 'general-info', 'config_general_info');
    add_submenu_page( 'mdw-config', 'Google Analytics Integration', 'Google Analytics', 'manage_options', 'ga-integration', 'config_ga_integration');
```

And then some more submenus. What it achieves is:

[image]

As you can see, **MDW Config**, which is second argument of `add_menu()` duplicates, it seems like it's submenu of itself. I'm pretty sure it's possible to avoid it, as for example *Appearance* menu, which is default one, links directly to it's *Themes* submenu.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    add_menu_page( 'MDW Config', 'MDW Config', 'manage_options', 'mdw-config', 'config_general_info', '', 45);
    add_submenu_page( 'mdw-config', 'General info', 'Info', 'manage_options', 'mdw-config', 'config_general_info');
    add_submenu_page( 'mdw-config', 'Google Analytics Integration', 'Google Analytics', 'manage_options', 'ga-integration', 'config_ga_integration');
```

What you have to do is simply overwrite the name of your first submenu page by assigning it to the same `menu-slug` but with different name.

Comment: Of course. I don't believe I didn't try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I find it's to do it quickly, is with css

```
#toplevel_page_bb-plugins .wp-submenu .wp-first-item {
            display: none;
}
```

Of course, you will replace `bb-plugins` with your menu slug. And add this in the admin css file of your plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I already thought of that, but what I am looking for is more **wordpress** solution. I'm sure there is one, as they do it themselves. When I make sure they don't (...) I will do it your way :).

Comment: I will try soon the @Sebastian solution, I didn't think enough about this...

Comment: Yeah it works! But thank you anyway!